# SELinux prevents auto-umount of ecryptfs

Tags: selinux, automounting, unmounting, ecryptfs

I'm running SELinux and ecryptfs on a Debian machine. When a user logs out, unfortunately it's home directory is not unmounted, and I get the following error in `audit.log`:

```
type=USER_AVC msg=audit(1458988069.562:251578): pid=1 uid=0
auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 
msg='Unknown permission stop for class system exe="/lib/systemd/systemd"
sauid=0 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
```

`audit2allow` doesn't suggest a solution for this. It doesn't even mention this error. I had found [this bugreport](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1296570), but unfortunately it doesn't suggest any workaround, and it doesn't look like it will be fixed in the near future. I had tried to add the following line to my local SELinux rules, but no success:

```
allow systemd_logind_t init_t:service { start status stop };
```

Any better ideas?